# Clean subtitle files with 'tm' package and parallel processing

Tags: r, parallel-processing, text-mining, tm

I have 150,000 subtitle files in the "File" format (because I forgot to add .txt to the end of each one when converting from .srt) for which I want to remove everything that isn't text in order to perform sentiment analysis. Here is a sample of one of the subtitle files:

```
1
00:00:14,542 --> 00:00:16,875
<i>Sarah Jane: For a long time,</i>

2
00:00:16,875 --> 00:00:20,542
<i>I'd walk into work
convinced they all knew,</i>

3
00:00:20,542 --> 00:00:23,500
<i>They saw right through me,
me and my innocent act,</i>
```

I have been using the "tm" package, but loading all the files into a corpus is very slow, since all the text files are 12GB in total. Here is the code I've been using:

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)

docs <- Corpus(DirSource("C:/Users/Alex/Downloads/Extracted/"))

toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) {return (gsub(pattern, " ", x))})
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "-")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ":")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "<i>")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "</i>")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "<b>")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "</b>")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "<u>")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "</u>")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, " -")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ",")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ">")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "^ ")
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "  ,       ,")
docs <- tm_map(docs,content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(gsub), pattern = " l ", replacement = "i")
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)

writeLines(as.character(docs[[1]]))
```

I then want to export each modified document in the corpus into a text file:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cores = detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1])
registerDoParallel(cl)

setwd("C:/Users/Alex/Downloads/Corpus/")

files  <- list.files(path="C:/Users/Alex/Downloads/Extracted/")

foreach(i=1:length(files), .combine=cbind) %dopar% {
  writeLines(as.character(docs[[i]]), con=paste0(files[i], ".txt"))
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Is there a way to speed up the `tm_map` function or would it be better to read each file individualy, modify it with `gsub` and write it to a file? If the second option is better, would I need to re-convert the files from .srt to .txt before proceding? (This took over 4 hours the first time around). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this at the command line, using some simple bash commands, and regular expressions to extract the text between the tags, but I assume you want to use R for this, so the solution below is the R way.  But it uses the **quanteda** package rather than **tm**.

```
# change for the location of your files
input_directory <- "~/tmp/test/"
output_directory <- input_directory

# reads in all of the text files
require(readtext)
txt <- readtext(input_directory)

require(quanteda)
require(magrittr)
txt2 <- 
    corpus(txt) %>%
    corpus_segment(what = "tag", delimiter = "</?i>") %>%
    corpus_subset(tag == "<i>") %>%
    texts(groups = "_document")

for (i in names(txt2)) {
    cat(txt2[i], file = paste0(output_directory, "/", i, ".txt"))
}
```

The `readtext` command reads in all of your files to a data.frame, and then the `corpus()` command constructs a **quanteda** corpus from them.  After that, the `corpus_segment()` separates the documents by the `<i>...</i>` tags which denote your text.  We then select out the text following the `<i>` tag, and regroup that by document id.  The final loop outputs the newly cleaned text into new files containing the `.txt` extension.

#### Just renaming files

Note that if you only wanted to rename your files, that does not require R at all.     In Linux or macOS, change to the directory where all your files are, and type this command:

```
`for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file}.txt"; done`
```

In Windows, you can do this if you have a bash shell, or you can follow the instructions [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/) on how to do this using the file explorer.